# Retrieve image from user class in Parse

Tags: ios, database, parse-platform, pfquery

I am trying to retrieve an image from parse.com, but can't figure out how!

I used this code to save image to the user class in parse.com:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0);
imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"profilePic" data:imageData];

PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
[user setObject:imageFile forKey:@"imageFile"];

[user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        NSLog(@"saved");
    }
}];
```

Now I want to retrieve the same image back and se it in the `imageView`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [getDataInBackgroundWithBlock](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFile.html#//api/name/getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:)

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
PFFile *userImageFile = user[@"imageFile"];
[userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't that hard, but I'm new to parse, and any kind of database programming what so ever ;)

Comment: Parse iOS guide is quite good. I would suggest you read it a couple of times :)

Comment: Could you answer this question too? I believe you know how to do it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190147/retrieve-boolean-from-user-class-in-parse