# Retrieve boolean from user class in Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I can't figure out how to retrieve a boolean from the user class in Parse. This code doesn't work for me:

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
NSNumber *boolNumber = [user objectForKey:@"bool"];
BOOL b = [boolNumber boolValue];
NSLog(@"%d", b);
```

Anyone know the proper way to do this?

Comment: It looks fine to me, what error are you getting?

Comment: There's no error, just doesn't seem to work, since I get 0 logged all the time. The returned boolean value is never correct. If you understand what I mean...

Answer (score 2):

Everything you're doing looks fine on retrieval. It's probably an error with the way you are setting the variable/saving the user. Try something like this and see if it works.

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
user[@"likesFruit"] = @(YES); // You can set it to @(NO) also. It doesn't matter. This is just an example.
[user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        BOOL likesFruit = [user[@"likesFruit"] boolValue];
        NSLog(@"Does this user like fruit?\n%@", (likesFruit) ? @"Yes" : @"No");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error saving user: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Another way to make sure your retrieval is safe is this:

```
[user fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        BOOL likesFruit = [object[@"likesFruit"] boolValue];
        NSLog(@"This user %@ like fruit", likesFruit ? @"does" : @"doesn't");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error retrieving user data: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: With my code the problem was the boolean column wasn't fetched, but with your code the column gets fetched. But here the boolean is always YES, since you set it to yes in the second line.. I think. Thats not what I want.. If you understand

Comment: @Peter You don't have to set it to YES for this to work.

Comment: But I want the boolean to say YES or NO depending on the boolean from parse. Not depending on if I write @(YES) or @(NO) in the second line...

Comment: @Peter Dude, think for yourself for a minute... Solution: remove that line of code, it's just an example.

Comment: Okey my bad. But when I change the boolean value in parse.com, it doesn't change when I fetch it next time.. it stays the same, 0. whether it is True or False in Parse, it's always 0 when I fetch it...

Comment: @Peter Last comment: Use the second option I presented, if that doesn't work, make sure you're working with the right PFUser. To do so, check the `objectId` of the current user and make sure it's the same as the one you're modifying from the Parse.com dashboard

Comment: Same problem still, I think I know the problem now! Doesn't seem like parse is updating itself. If I add a column manually in parse.com, it doesn't show up in Xcode. If I change column value it doesn't change in Xcode. I check it in the estimatedData in the debugger. No idea what this means though..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
BOOL boolean = [[user objectForKey@"bool"] boolValue];
```

Comment: Doesn't work, same problem as with my code. The boolean value is just not there..

Comment: Are you fetching the the data for the user?

Comment: Did you retrieve the data from the cloud? Try calling `[user refresh];` or fetchIfNeeded.

Comment: Is there a way to check if I got the data I was supposed to?

Comment: You could print out the properties to the console or use the debugger to inspect the user object after retrieving data from the cloud. I think the properties are stored under estimatedData.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58911/discussion-between-john-slade-and-peter).